# outline for a custom document format

Tags: visual-studio-code

The same way HTML and JSON (but not YAML?) already have their navigable Outline, I would like to add the same ability for my custom format, to help me navigate thru lengthy text.
Where I can find documentation for doing so?

I have found "how to add a grammar for highlighting" which is partially useful, (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide), but not sure following this guide will provide me an Outline, again, YAML for ex. is highlighted, but doesn't appear in Outline.

Admittedly, I haven't read the entirety of the above link, but the word "Outline" doesn't appear, and I have trouble to filter search engine results.

Example below:

```
{
   "doc1": {
      "key": 12,
      "a": [
         1,
         2,
         3
      ]
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: does the Language Server doc pages mention this view, I think for Python and JavaScript it is the LS that provides the data to show because you need to analyze the code

Comment: @rioV8 but a random JSON file gets its own outline automatically?

Comment: then analyze the JSON extension how it feeds the OUTLINE View, it does not happen without any code calculating the content, it could be an API that is not available to external extension developers